# Leetcode 9. Palindrome Number

Tags: java, if-statement, palindrome

I am trying to do this converting the integer to a string.
Inside the `if` clause, if I used `s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)` first then `i++`, `j--`, I couldn't pass the test of input = 121, I got false instead of true. But if I put `s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(j)` first, then accepted.

Wrong answer:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        String s = String.valueOf(x); //n
        int l = s.length();
        int i = 0;
        int j = l - 1;
        while (i <= j) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                i++;
                j--;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Accepted answer:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        String s = String.valueOf(x); //n
        int l = s.length();
        int i = 0;
        int j = l - 1;
        while (i <= j) {
            if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(j)) {
                return false;
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

What did I miss?

Comment: maybe you should start using a debugger to execute the code step by step and see the different logic of each

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong solution returns `false` in any case and the correct solution only returns `false` when `s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(j)` is true.

If you want to skip `return false;` in the first code, you either need to move it into an `else` clause or use `continue;` in the `if` clause in order to directly jump to the next loop iteration.